# Proper way to do session handling in Python + Pylons for a php programmer

Tags: python, session, pylons

I'm a php programmer who's just getting started with Python.  I'm trying to get Python to handle login/logout via database-stored sessions.  Things work, but seem inconsistent.  For example, sometimes a user isn't logged out.  Sometimes users "switch" logins.  I'm guessing this has something to do with thread-safety, but I'm just not sure where to begin on how to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here's what I have now:

```
#lib/base.py

def authenticate():
#Confirm login
 try:
     if user['authenticated'] != True:
         redirect_to(controller='login', action='index')
 except KeyError:
     redirect_to(controller='login', action='index')

#Global variables
user = {}
connection = {}

class BaseController(WSGIController):

#Read if there is a cookie set
     try:
         session = request.cookies['session']

         #Create a session object from the session id
         session_logged_in = Session(session)

         #If the session is valid, retrieve the user info
         if session_logged_in.isValid(remote_addr):

             #Set global variables about the logged in user
             user_logged_in = User(session_logged_in.user_id)
             user['name'] = c.name = user_logged_in.name
             user['name_url'] = c.name_url = user_logged_in.name_url
             user['first_name'] = c.first_name = user_logged_in.first_name
             user['last_name'] = c.last_name = user_logged_in.last_name
             user['email'] = c.email = user_logged_in.email
             user['about'] = c.about = user_logged_in.about
             user['authenticated'] = c.authenticated = True
             user['profile_url'] = c.profile_url = user_logged_in.profile_url 
             user['user_thumb'] = c.user_thumb = user_logged_in.user_thumb
             user['image_id'] = c.image_id = user_logged_in.image_id
             user['id'] = c.user_id = user_logged_in.id

             #Update the session
             session_logged_in.current_uri = requested_url
             session_logged_in.update()

     #If no session has been set, do nothing
     except KeyError:
         user['authenticated'] = False
```

I can then access the user{} global from my controllers:

```
#controllers/profile.py
from project.lib.base import BaseController, user
class ProfileController(BaseController):

    def index(self, id=None, name_url=None):

        #If this is you
         if user['id'] == 1
             print 'this is you'
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have not worked with Pylons sessions yet so I am not of any help. But since you are starting out with Python, I might suggest to refactor your authenticate function like this: if not user.get('authenticated', False): redirect(blah blah), that way, you don't have to catch KeyError exceptions.

Comment: Thank you.  I will implement this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pylons has a 'sessions' object that exists to handle this kind of situation. The [example](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/sessions/) on the Pylons website seems to match what you want.

I think you are seeing problems because of the globals 'user' and 'connection'. Pylons has a [globals](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Getting+Started#application-globals-and-persistent-objects) object that is designed to share information between all controllers and is not reset on each request.